# rendering html templates golang revel

Tags: go, struct, revel, go-html-template

I am hoping someone will be able to help me out. I have started building a web app and decided to go with GO and Revel. So far I've learnt quite a few things but there is this one functionality I can't seem to be able to get working. I have the following code:

```
package controllers

import (
"github.com/revel/revel"
_ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
"database/sql")

type App struct {
*revel.Controller
}

type resultRow struct {
TransactionDomain string
TransactionType string
TransactionIsoResponse string
Store string
Terminal string
Vendor string
RequestDT string
ResponseDT string
AccountDisplay string
AccountDetails1 string
InvoiceNumber string
Amount string
}

type colNames struct {
Name string
}

type resultTable struct {
fpk string
columns []colNames
resultRows []resultRow
}
func (c App) FpkTable() revel.Result {
//all db section goes here. I have confirmed the results are obtaind back 
//from the db.
    err = rows.Scan(&resRow.TransactionDomain,
        &resRow.TransactionType,
        &resRow.TransactionIsoResponse,
        &resRow.Store,
        &resRow.Terminal,
        &resRow.Vendor,
        &resRow.RequestDT,
        &resRow.ResponseDT,
        &resRow.AccountDisplay,
        &resRow.AccountDetails1,
        &resRow.InvoiceNumber,
        &resRow.Amount)
    if err != nil {
        revel.INFO.Println("Scan failed:", err.Error())
    }
    arrRow = append(arrRow, resRow)
}
columnNames := []colNames{{Name:"Domain"}, {Name:"Type"}, {Name:"Vendor Response"}, {Name:"Store"}, {Name:"Register"}, 
{Name:"Request DT"}, {Name:"Response DT"}, {Name:"Account"}, {Name:"Token"}, {Name:"Invoice"}, {Name:"Amount"}}
table := &resultTable{c.Request.FormValue("store") + "-" + c.Request.FormValue("register") + "-" + c.Request.FormValue("invoice") + "-" + c.Request.FormValue("date"), columnNames, arrRow}
return c.Render(table)
```

I have the following html template:

```
<div class="row">
    <a>{{.fpk}}</a>
    <ul>
        {{range .columns}}
        <li>{{.Name}}</li>
        {{end}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

And I am expecting to see something like this

```
<div class="row">
    <a>AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Domain</li>
        <li>Type</li>
        .
        .
        .
    </ul>
</div>
```

But Instead I am getting no values passed into the template at

```
 <div class="row">
    <a></a>
        <ul>

        </ul>
        ::after
        //This line makes me believe the processing of the
        //template is being done properly except the data 
        //is not being passed properly to the template.
 </div>
```

I have gone through every possible site wondering about this but I haven't been able to find a solution.

I am sure this will be something simple but anyhow, thanks for any help you might be able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your template syntax, usually I range doing it like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <a>{{.fpk}}</a>
    <ul>
        {{range $index, $element := .columns}}
        <li>{{$element.Name}}</li>
        {{end}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Another thing that I can think off is that your data may be empty, have you tried checking the columns struct field to see if it contains data?

Comment: Yep, I have made sure the data is there in the struct, I'll give it a try with your suggestion and let you know if it works, thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I have been able to figure this one out.